# php redirect from include file

Tags: php, redirect, include

When I add the php redirect command in an include file, it redirects just that area, in its little sub window.

How can I make a redirect work with the base page?

Is it even possible, because you can only redirect before the headers, can't you? Would I have to use javascript instead?

Comment: Do You use frames, iframes, html objects or something like this?

Answer (score 1):

### If you are not talking about iframes

You can use [output buffering](http://php.net/ob_start) to get round this issue. At the beginning of your main script run:

```
ob_start();
```

And then once you are done at the bottom of your main script run:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

From the manual page linked above:

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is
>   active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> The contents of this internal buffer may be copied into a string
>   variable using ob_get_contents(). To output what is stored in the
>   internal buffer, use ob_end_flush(). Alternatively, ob_end_clean()
>   will silently discard the buffer contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect parent window from `<iframe` (I assume that's what you mean by "little sub window") you have to use javascript, probably: `self.parent.location.href = '...';`

Google for [javascript parent redirect](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=740428) to get more examples.

Comment: Nah im not using frames, I just meant the include is like its own little window.

Comment: That the Treffynnons answer is right and you could use `Header( 'Location: ')` any time